# adding multiple marker on google map from spinner, main class is MapActivity android studio

Tags: php, android, google-maps

[drop down list of my app and set the marker from latLng my campus.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UTQtN.png)

So that is display application that I made using android studio. The initial view of the marker can I set, I set corresponding latitude and longitude from my campus. Users can choose the drop down list, a dropdown list is there are 2, select "Masjid" or select "Mushola".

Suppose the user select "Masjid", and user continue to press enter on the button. Well,  marker still has not come out. Image below:

[Marker still has not come out](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aD7VR.png)

My code Masjid.java

```
package com.example.handy.testmapsnew;

public class Masjid {

public int idMasjid;
public String namaMasjid, alamatMasjid;
public double lat, lng;

public Masjid(int idMasjid, String namaMasjid, String alamatMasjid, double lat, double lng){

            this.idMasjid = idMasjid;
            this.namaMasjid = namaMasjid;
            this.alamatMasjid = alamatMasjid;
            this.lat = lat;
            this.lng = lng;

        }}
```

---

My code MapsActivity.java

```
package com.example.handy.testmapsnew;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Spinner;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements
OnMapReadyCallback, AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {
  private GoogleMap mMap;
  // Might be null if Google Play services APK is not available.
  String masjidataumushola;
  public ArrayList < Masjid > MASJID;
  //localhost database
  String urlMasjid = "http://10.0.2.2/papb/masjid.php";

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
    setUpMapIfNeeded();
    onMapReady(mMap);


    Spinner pilihMasjid = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.pilihMasjid);
    pilihMasjid.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
    List < String > categories = new ArrayList < > ();
    categories.add("Masjid");
    categories.add("Mushola");

    ArrayAdapter < String > dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter < String > (this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, categories);
    dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    pilihMasjid.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
  }

  @Override
  protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    setUpMapIfNeeded();
    onMapReady(mMap);
  }


  public void onSearch(View view) {

    switch (masjidataumushola) {
      case "Masjid":
        mMap.clear();
        addMarkertoMap(MASJID);
        MasjidMushola masjidMushola = new MasjidMushola();
        masjidMushola.execute("http://10.0.2.2/papb/masjid.php");
        break;
      case "Mushola":
        mMap.clear();
        addMarkertoMap(MASJID);
        MasjidMushola masjidMushola1 = new MasjidMushola();
        masjidMushola1.execute("http://10.0.2.2/papb/masjid.php");
        break;

      default:
        break;
    }

  }

  public void onZoom(View view) {
    if (view.getId() == R.id.Bzoomin) {
      mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomIn());
    }
    if (view.getId() == R.id.Bzoomout) {
      mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomOut());
    }
  }

  public void changeType(View view) {
    if (mMap.getMapType() == GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL) {
      mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_SATELLITE);
    } else
      mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);
  }

  private void setUpMapIfNeeded() {
    // Do a null check to confirm that we have not already instantiated the map.
    if (mMap == null) {
      // Try to obtain the map from the SupportMapFragment.
      mMap = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map))
        .getMap();
      // Check if we were successful in obtaining the map.
      if (mMap != null) {

        //setUpMap();
      }
    }
  }

  private void setUpMap() {
    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(0, 0)).title("Marker"));



  }

  @Override
  public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap;
    LatLng malang = new LatLng(-7.9517279, 112.6127167);

    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(malang).title("Malang"));
    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(malang, 12));
  }

  @Override
  public void onItemSelected(AdapterView < ? > parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    String item = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
    masjidataumushola = item;
  }

  @Override
  public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView < ? > parent) {

  }

  public void addMarkertoMap(ArrayList < Masjid > masjids) {

    try {
      for (int i = 0; i < masjids.size(); i++) {
        double lat = Double.parseDouble(String.valueOf(masjids.get(i).lat));
        double lon = Double.parseDouble(String.valueOf(masjids.get(i).lng));
        LatLng letakMasjid = new LatLng(lat, lon);
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(letakMasjid)
          .title(masjids.get(i).namaMasjid)
          .snippet(masjids.get(i).alamatMasjid));
      }
    } catch (Exception ex) {}
  }

  /**
   * Asynctask inner class
   */

  public class MasjidMushola extends AsyncTask < String, String, List < Masjid >> {


    @Override
    protected List < Masjid > doInBackground(String...params) {

      List < Masjid > masjids = new ArrayList < Masjid > ();
      String query = null;
      String queryReturn = null;
      String result = null;

      try {

        query = params[0];
        queryReturn = sendQuery(query);
        result += ParseJSON(queryReturn);


      } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      }

      return masjids;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(List < Masjid > masjids) {
      super.onPostExecute(masjids);

      try {
        for (int i = 0; i < masjids.size(); i++) {
          double lat = Double.parseDouble(String.valueOf(masjids.get(i).lat));
          double lon = Double.parseDouble(String.valueOf(masjids.get(i).lng));
          LatLng letakMasjid = new LatLng(lat, lon);
          mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(letakMasjid)
            .title(masjids.get(i).namaMasjid)
            .snippet(masjids.get(i).alamatMasjid));
        }
      } catch (Exception ex) {}
    }

    private String sendQuery(String query) {
      String result = "";


      try {

        URL url = new URL(query);

        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        if (connection.getResponseCode() == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
          InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream());
          BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(
            isr,
            8192);

          String line;
          while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            result += line;
          }

          br.close();
        }

      } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      }

      return result;
    }


    /**
     * method ParseJSON
     * @param json
     * @return
     */

    private String ParseJSON(String json) {
      String jsonResult = "";

      try {
        JSONObject JsonObject = new JSONObject(json);
        String cod = jsonHelperGetString(JsonObject, "cod");

        if (cod != null) {
          if (cod.equals("200")) {

            jsonResult += jsonHelperGetString(JsonObject, "name") + "\n";
            JSONObject result = jsonHelperGetJSONObject(JsonObject, "result");
            jsonResult += "\n";

            JSONArray arrayResult = jsonHelperGetJSONArray(JsonObject, "weather");
            if (result != null) {
              for (int i = 0; i < result.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject thisWeather = arrayResult.getJSONObject(i);
                jsonResult += "weather " + i + ":\n";
                jsonResult += "nama_masjid: " + jsonHelperGetString(thisWeather, "nama_masjid") + "\n";
                jsonResult += "alamat_masjid" + jsonHelperGetString(thisWeather, "alamat_masjid") + "\n";
                jsonResult += "lat" + jsonHelperGetString(thisWeather, "latitude") + "\n";
                jsonResult += "lng" + jsonHelperGetString(thisWeather, "longitude") + "\n";
                jsonResult += "\n";
              }
            }

          } else if (cod.equals("404")) {
            String message = jsonHelperGetString(JsonObject, "message");
            jsonResult += "cod 404: " + message;
          }
        } else {
          jsonResult += "cod == null\n";
        }

      } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();

      }
      addMarkertoMap(MASJID);
      return jsonResult;
    }

    private String jsonHelperGetString(JSONObject obj, String k) {
      String jsonString = null;
      try {
        jsonString = obj.getString(k);
      } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      }

      return jsonString;
    }

    /**
     * @param object: JSONObject
     * @param k:      String
     * @return jsonObject
     */

    private JSONObject jsonHelperGetJSONObject(JSONObject object, String k) {
      JSONObject jsonObject = null;

      try {
        jsonObject = object.getJSONObject(k);
      } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      }

      return jsonObject;
    }

    /**
     * Change JSONObject to String
     *
     * @param object: JSONObject
     * @param k:      String
     * @return String jsonArray
     */

    private JSONArray jsonHelperGetJSONArray(JSONObject object, String k) {
      JSONArray jsonArray = null;

      try {
        jsonArray = object.getJSONArray(k);
      } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      }

      return jsonArray;
    }

  }

}
```

---

My code on php file in htdocs/papb/masjid.php

```
<?php
define('HOST','localhost');
define('USER','root');
define('PASS','');
define('DB','masjid');

$con = mysqli_connect(HOST,USER,PASS,DB);

$sql = "select * from data_masjid";

$res = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
$result = array();

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($res)){
    array_push($result,
        array('id'=>$row[0],
            'nama_masjid'=>$row[1],
            'alamat_masjid'=>$row[2],
            'latitude'=>$row[3],
            'longitude'=>$row[4]
        ));
}

echo json_encode(array("result"=>$result));

mysqli_close($con);

?>
```

The marker has not yet appeared. The problem is that to me is why the marker has not yet appeared? While I've got a database, json in PHP file also already exists. The 2nd problem is I'm confused at doInBackground method.
sorry for my English. Please help, thank you.

Comment: check is it throwing any exception ie whenever you write catch always call `exception.printstackstrace();`